# ng-google-chart how to expose draw() method

Tags: angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I've created a sample of my chart below using 
[nicholas bering, API Promise](http://nicholasbering.ca/angularjs/2015/04/02/google-charts-api-promise/).  I faked the $http data callback in my demo below.

My question is how to correctly access the draw() method of the chart after it is already displayed in the browser?

In my demo below, I create a google.visualization.DataView() so I can access the hideRows() method.  Once that occurs, the documentation says I need to call on the draw() method to repaint the chart with the newly altered row information.

In this case I'm trying to let the user hide rows of items where the quantity being displayed is zero (row 2 "Olives" in my data).  Once I get this working, I will let the user toggle other things but for now I'm trying to keep my question simple.

But this is where I get lost... the draw() method as I understand it should already exist on the original chart I created.  How does one expose the draw() method of the original chart without having to poke at the DOM with a document.getElementById('myBarChart').  This seems so unlike everything Angular.

Here is my code:

```
<div ng-controller="ChartsController as ChartsController"
 ng-init="ChartsController.init()">

    <button ng-click="ChartsController.ToggleZeroDistributionOff()">No Zeros</button><br>

    <div google-chart chart="chartMe"  id="myBarChart" />

</div>
```

now my controller:

```
'use strict';

app.controller('ChartsController', ['$scope', '$http', '$q', 'googleChartApiPromise', function ($scope, $http, $q, googleChartApiPromise) {

    this.name = "ChartsController";
    this.$inject = ['$scope', '$q', '$http', 'googleChartApiPromise'];

    $scope.chartMe = {};

    this.init = function () {
        // simulated $http callback data returned in promise
        var dataPromise = {
            "data": [
                {"itemname": "Mushrooms", "qty": 13 },
                {"itemname":"Onions", "qty": 11},
                {"itemname":"Olives", "qty": 0},
                {"itemname":"Zucchini", "qty": 1},
                {"itemname": "Pepperoni", "qty": 27 }
            ]
        }
        // bind data and chart loading before building the my chart
        $q.all({ data: dataPromise, api: googleChartApiPromise })
           .then(apiLoadSuccess);
    };


    function apiLoadSuccess(result) {
        $scope.chartMe.type = 'BarChart'; 
        //create a new DataTable loaded with data from the HTTP response
        $scope.chartMe.data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        $scope.chartMe.data.addColumn('string', 'Item Name/Units');
        $scope.chartMe.data.addColumn('number', 'Qty');
         // create an array to hold index of items 
        var aNoQty = [];
        var aQty = [];
        var aRows = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < result.data.data.length; i++) {
            var oData = [];
            aRows.push(i);
            oData[0] = result.data.data[i].itemname; 
            oData[1] = result.data.data[i].qty;
            // which items quanity exist
            if (result.data.data[i].qty > 0) {
                aQty.push(i);
            } else {
                aNoQty.push(i);
            };
            // now add the row
            $scope.chartMe.data.addRow(oData);
        };

        $scope.aNoQty = aNoQty;
        $scope.aQty = aQty;

        $scope.chartMe.options = {
            title: "Item(s) Distributed",
            isStacked: false,
            displayExactValues: true,
        };
    };

    this.ToggleZeroDistributionOff = function () {
        $scope.chartMe.view = new google.visualization.DataView($scope.chartMe.data);
        $scope.chartMe.view.hideRows($scope.aNoQty)

        // this seems like the wrong way to attach to existing chart...
        // i'm referring to using document.getElementById() - not very Angular !
        // but how else to expose the draw() method ??
        var myChart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('myBarChart'));
        // now draw() method is expoised
        myChart.draw($scope.chartMe.view.toDataTable(), $scope.chartMe.options)
    }
}]);
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: It is my understanding to use google.visualization.BarChart( DOM_Reference_Required ) which I understood from prior readings, direct access to DOM elements is frond upon and not recommended in angular.  Maybe I'm wrong but without referencing the DOM element, I guess I'm wondering ng-google-chart has a solution like ng-model.

Comment: you could use the [`ChartWrapper class`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#chartwrapper-class) instead, it requires only the id of the element, plus the data table and options are embedded, such that calling `draw()` requires no arguments...

Comment: I ended up using your earlier comment about adding the myChart to $scope.chartMe which works perfectly.   (i.e. $scope.chartMe.myChart = ...) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you WhiteHat for your suggestion.  It worked both ways but in my case found your first answer to be easier to work with.

I posted a complete solution below:

```
'use strict';

app.controller('ChartsController', ['$scope', '$http', '$q', 
'googleChartApiPromise', function ($scope, $http, $q, googleChartApiPromise) {

this.name = "ChartsController";
this.$inject = ['$scope', '$q', '$http', 'googleChartApiPromise'];

$scope.chartMe = {};

this.init = function () {
    // simulated $http callback data returned in promise
    var dataPromise = {
        "data": [
            {"itemname": "Mushrooms", "qty": 13 },
            {"itemname":"Onions", "qty": 11},
            {"itemname":"Olives", "qty": 0},
            {"itemname":"Zucchini", "qty": 1},
            {"itemname": "Pepperoni", "qty": 27 }
        ]
    }
    // bind data and chart loading before building the my chart
    $q.all({ data: dataPromise, api: googleChartApiPromise })
       .then(apiLoadSuccess);
};


function apiLoadSuccess(result) {
    $scope.chartMe.type = 'BarChart'; 
    //create a new DataTable loaded with data from the HTTP response
    $scope.chartMe.data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    $scope.chartMe.data.addColumn('string', 'Item Name/Units');
    $scope.chartMe.data.addColumn('number', 'Qty');
     // create an array to hold index of items 
    var aNoQty = [];
    var aQty = [];
    var aRows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < result.data.data.length; i++) {
        var oData = [];
        aRows.push(i);
        oData[0] = result.data.data[i].itemname; 
        oData[1] = result.data.data[i].qty;
        // which items quanity exist
        if (result.data.data[i].qty > 0) {
            aQty.push(i);
        } else {
            aNoQty.push(i);
        };
        // now add the row
        $scope.chartMe.data.addRow(oData);
    };

    $scope.aNoQty = aNoQty;
    $scope.aQty = aQty;

    $scope.chartMe.options = {
        title: "Item(s) Distributed",
        isStacked: false,
        displayExactValues: true,
    };

    // chart view used later
    $scope.chartMe.view = new google.visualization.DataView($scope.chartMe.data);
    // grab a reference to the chart
    $scope.chartMe.myChart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('myBarChart'));

};

this.ToggleZeroDistributionOff = function () {
    // $scope.chartMe.view = new google.visualization.DataView($scope.chartMe.data);
    $scope.chartMe.view.hideRows($scope.aNoQty)

    // draw() method exists so refresh with new view
    $scope.chartMe.myChart.draw($scope.chartMe.view.toDataTable(), $scope.chartMe.options)
}
```

}]);

This worked for me and opened lots of new options.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Another way to hide rows as a response to an input in the view, assuming that you don't have that much data, is to use **ng-change** and set
the value of the cells in your row(s)/column(s) to = null. You'll have to find all the cells that you want to set to null because you can't simply set the 
whole row or column to null. One by one. The advantage is that you can stick to the simple way of using ng-google-charts. Again this might make things easier only for small charts. You can also write a function which does a push() to the table an put in the ng-change of your input to do insert data from the view. If you ng-change affects directly the DataTable, make a variable that stores the original values, that way you can hide and then restore columns or rows.

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-change.asp